# Как в Linux настроить Denwer + Spark + Kotlin?

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, kotlin, denwer, spark-framework

Всем привет! Появилось желание писать сервер (вернее, апи часть) на локалке под линуксом, причем писать на Kotlin-е
Я так понял, мне необходимо настроить денвер и на нем фреймворк SparkJava, а уже потом подключить плагин Kotlin-а
Не смог, к сожалению, найти информацию, мне кажется денвер работает только с php. Подскажите краткую инструкцию как все сделать без косяков, может кто-то уже делал такое

Comment: Kotlin компилируется в обычный jar(war) архив. Никаких специальных плясок вокруг веб-сервера производить не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего особо сложного, как я изначально представлял. Просто создал проект в IDEA, подключил SparkJava, скомпилировал и локальный сервер стал доступен по ссылке `localhost:4567`. Никаких дополнительных действий не понадобилось.